# How to read the JSON values from the unstructured data in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, json.net

```
{
  "id": "zd_tags",
  "value": [
    "bp_ticket;pazure_server"
  ]
},
{
  "id": "itd_priority_1",
  "value": 900
},
{
  "id": "impacted_services",
  "value": [
    "Serverdown0208_2"
  ]
},
```

I am unable to read and deserialize the JSON into my objects which throws the below error.

```
"$.incidentTags[6].value": [
  "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String[]. Path: $.incidentTags[6].value | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1856."
]
```

Below is my current structure to deserialize it.

```
 public class  incidentTag
{
public string id { get; set; }
public string[] value {get;set;}

 }
```

Here is the problem, Some tag has no array " "id": "itd_priority_1"  but many have an array of value.

What is the best way to handle this scenario?

Comment: So, sometimes `value` is an array of strings, other times an integer?  You'll need to make it `object` or `dynamic` in your code and then figure out what to do inside the code by checking the type of the deserialized object

Answer (score 1):

Cant make a comment so having to make an answer.

Previously I have used a dynamic for if the data is unstructured or I don't know the data structure. An example of how I have used a dynamic is below

```
FeedResponse<dynamic> resultSet = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync();
                foreach (dynamic item in resultSet)
                {
                    tasks.Add(_targetContainer.CreateItemAsync(item.Something));
                }
```

I presume similar could be applied to your use case

Answer (score 1):

Either you can create a [custom json converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) to handle the parsing the way you want it, there are many examples you can look for it.

Or as an altenative you can use `JObject`, something like this, parse the json and visit the `JPproperty` in `JObject` and check whether that is array or object or any other primitive type.

```
JObject jObject = JObject.parse(your json);
foreach (var property in jObject.Properties())
{
   VisitToken(property.Value);
}    

private void VisitToken(JToken token)
{
    switch (token.Type)
    {
        case JTokenType.Object:
             VisitJObject(token.Value<JObject>());
             break;

        case JTokenType.Array:
             VisitArray(token.Value<JArray>());
             break;

        case JTokenType.Integer:
             case JTokenType.Float:
             case JTokenType.String:
             case JTokenType.Boolean:
             case JTokenType.Bytes:
             case JTokenType.Raw:
             case JTokenType.Null:
                  VisitPrimitive(token);
                  break;    
         default:
                  throw new FormatException($"Invalid JSON token: {token}");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually create a json constructor in this case

```
List<incidentTag> incidentTags = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<incidentTag>>(json);

public class incidentTag
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string[] value { get; set; }
    [JsonConstructor]
    public incidentTag(JToken value)
    {
        if (value.Type.ToString() == "Array") this.value = value.ToObject<string[]>();
        else
        {
            this.value = new string[] { value.ToString() };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Old Post for fixing this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n)

The Above link helped me to resolve the problem and one more thing is, need to add the reference for "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson;".I guess,  .Net core 6 is using the System.text.Json which has an issue or does not support this operation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).